# Graph dimension decreases if CheckList is used to update y axis

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Dash App that represents graphs about data in a database. One column of the database is a list of journals and I represented this column in a pie and in a bar chart with the respective frequency of each journal. I decided to put also a CheckList, because the database can change and if there are too many journals, the graphs are no more readable. So at the beginning only the first 15 items of the list are shown in the graphs, like the image below.

[image]

The problem is that, if I change the selected journals in the Checklist, the graphs update correctly but the width of the bar chart decreases and I don't understand why. In the image below it is possible to see that, changing the selection, the graph dimension is reduced and re-checking the two items, the graph does not return with the initial dimension anymore. Why?

[image]

(The graphs are created in a callback after the selection of the database in a dropdown)

```
@app.callback(
    Output('first_graph', 'children'),
    Input('database', 'value')
)
def create_graph(value):
    if value is not None: #if i select the database from a dropdown, the graphs appear
        df = pd.read_csv(value)

        
        #Count unique values: index takes the values, the other takes the counts
        journals = df['Journal'].value_counts().index.tolist() # --> x
        journals_frequency = df['Journal'].value_counts().tolist()  # --> y
        trace1 = go.Bar(y=journals, x=journals_frequency,orientation='h', name='Number of journals',
                        marker=dict(color=color_charts_journals)) #'h' stays for horizontal
        
        layout1 = go.Layout(autosize=False,
                            width=450,
                            height=350,
                            xaxis=dict(tickformat=',d', showgrid=False),
                            yaxis=dict(type='category', tickmode='linear', showticklabels=False, showgrid=False),
                            margin=dict(t=25,b=25,l=5,r=5),
                            bargap=0,
                            )

        fig1=go.Figure(data=[trace1],layout=layout1)


        pie_journals = go.Pie(labels=journals, values=journals_frequency, hole=0.5, showlegend=False,textposition='inside',
                               name='Frequency of Journals',marker=dict(colors=color_charts_journals))
        fig_pie_journals = go.Figure(data=[pie_journals])
        fig_pie_journals.update_layout(title={
                            'text': "Frequency of journals",
                            'y':1,
                            'x':0.5,
                            'xanchor': 'center',
                            'yanchor': 'top'},
                            autosize=False,
                            width=450,
                            height=350,
                            margin=dict(t=20, b=15, l=5, r=5),)

        
        return  html.B('List of journals', style={'textAlign': 'center','width': '50%'}),
                html.Div([
                dcc.Checklist(
                    id="all-or-none",
                    options=[{"label": "Select All", "value": "All"}],
                    value=[],
                )]),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Checklist(
                    id='checklist_journals',
                    options=[
                        {'label': x, 'value': x, 'disabled': False}
                        for x in sorted(journals) #set in alphabetical order
                    ],
                    value=sorted(journals)[0:15],
                    labelStyle={'display': 'block','margin-left':'40px','margin-top':'10px'}
                )],style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"overflow-y":"scroll","height": "350px"}), #'backgroundColor':'blue'
                html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='journals_pie',figure=fig_pie_journals)],style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='journals_graph', figure=fig1)],style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                

#callback for select all values of the checklist
@app.callback(
    Output("checklist_journals", "value"),
    [Input("all-or-none", "value")],
    [State("checklist_journals", "options"),State("checklist_journals", "value")],
)
def select_all_none(all_selected, options, values_checklist):
    if all_selected: #se clicco seleziona tutto
        all_or_none = []
        all_or_none = [option["value"] for option in options if all_selected]
        return all_or_none
    else:
        return values_checklist[0:15] #se non clicco seleziona i primi 15 altrimenti si tolgono tutti


#callback to choose values in pie journals and bar journals
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='journals_pie', component_property='figure'),Output('journals_graph','figure')],
    [Input('database', 'value'),Input(component_id='checklist_journals', component_property='value')]
)
def update_graph(value,options_chosen):
    if value is not None: 
        df = pd.read_csv(value)
        dff = df[df['Journal'].isin(options_chosen)] #dataframe with only selected journals

        journals = dff['Journal'].value_counts().index.tolist()  # --> x
        journals_frequency = dff['Journal'].value_counts().tolist()  # --> y

        pie_journals = go.Pie(labels=journals, values=journals_frequency, showlegend=False, hole=0.5,textposition='inside',
                               name='Frequency of Journals',marker=dict(colors=color_charts_journals))

        fig_pie_journals = go.Figure(data=[pie_journals])
        fig_pie_journals.update_layout(title={
                            'text': "Frequency of journals",
                            'y':1,
                            'x':0.5,
                            'xanchor': 'center',
                            'yanchor': 'top'},
                            autosize=False,
                            width=450,
                            height=350,
                            margin=dict(t=20, b=15, l=5, r=5),)
                            #paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue") #per settare le dimensioni della torta

        trace1 = go.Bar(y=journals, x=journals_frequency, orientation='h', name='Number of journals',
                        marker=dict(color=color_charts_journals))  # 'h' stays for horizontal
        layout1 = go.Layout(autosize=False,
                            width=450,
                            height=350,
                            xaxis=dict(tickformat=',d', showgrid=False),
                            yaxis=dict(type='category', tickmode='linear', showticklabels=False, showgrid=False),
                            margin=dict(t=25,b=25,l=5,r=5),
                            bargap=0,
                            #paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue",

                            #per avere massimo 20 valori
                            #yaxis=dict(type='category', tickmode='auto', showgrid=False,
                            #          automargin=False, nticks=20, tickwidth=10),
                            )
        fig1 = go.Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout1)#to set bar width

        return fig_pie_journals,fig1
    else:
        return dash.no_update,dash.no_update
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do you have your HTML diva in the callback and not in the layout like the many examples on the dash tutorials?

Comment: Because I want that the graphs appear only if I select the dropdown, so I have to put them returned in callback. And if I deselect the dropdow, the graphs disappears.